# 64-bit OS on a 32-bit processor

Tags: 64-bit

Can we install a 64-bit OS in a system having 32-bit processor?

Comment: You've tagged this x64 so you're talking about PCs - can you really buy 32-bit only processors nowadays? My 2004 desktop is 64-bit.

Comment: Funnily, you can install a 64 bit OS in a virtual machine on a 64 bit processor running in 32 bit mode under a 32 bit operating system. Don't ask me how this works, it is pure madness, but it sure works perfectly well (using it every day).

Comment: its cause of vt extension related witchcraft.

Comment: Can you fit a 2" pipe *inside* a 1" pipe?

Comment: sure. all you need is to bend space itself.

Comment: Processors have been supporting 64 bit instructions for a LONG time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only option would be emulation (such as qemu), but that requires a 32bit system underneath, and won't be very useful in practice (*very* slow, RAM still limited)

Answer (score 11):

No,

You can install a 32bit OS on a machine with a 64bit CPU, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is no

The longer answer is, there's quite a few reasons you wouldn't want to do so, even if you could.

1. [64 bit windows may perform worse than 32 bit windows with less than 4 gb of ram](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/5709#toc2)
   this may or may not be true for linux
2. [32 bit only systems were phased out by intel in 2004](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_microprocessors#Pentium_4F)  [AMD did it around 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_microprocessors#K6_architecture_.281997.E2.80.932001.29)
   so there's no point running the latest and greatest os on it.
3. your processor may be 64 bit, and be running 32 bit - check it up - in which case there's no issue- other than that you may want to run a 32 bit OS
4. Its more likely that the hardware for your geriatric 32 bit era system is supported on a 32 bit os than a 64 bit os
5. it is more likely that your software will run on 32 bit than 64 bit , tho there's sxs on windows, and the ability to run mixed libraries on linux.
6. it just wouldn't run. If it did its a 64 bit system. If it didn't you wasted your time. You can check with something like [cpu-z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) or [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/) on windows, or lshw on linux.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see how that could work.